# Redux-form - populate select from an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

This is a noob question, so please be indulgent. any help is much appreciated. I have dropdown select field `household`, that I need populated from an array `list`. The array `list` is initially blank and gets populated from a function `getHouses` (which is a a API get call). How do I use that array to populate my select field?

function `getHouses`:

```
 const List = []
 function getHouses() {
let token = localStorage.getItem('id_token') || null;
const AuthStr = 'Bearer '.concat(token);
axios.get(BASE_URL + 'household/list', { headers: { Authorization: AuthStr } }).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    let myData = response.data;
    console.log(myData);
    for (let i = 0; i < myData._embedded.length; i++) {
        let embedded = myData._embedded[i];
        List.push(embedded.friendlyName);
    }
    console.log(List);
    //this.setState({data:list});

}).catch((error) => {
        console.log('error' + error);
    });
}
```

The `select` field

```
 <Field name="family" component={renderDropdownList} data={List} label="family" className="form-control"                          placeholder="select your family" />
```

What do I need to do? I'm not yet very good at managing states (beginner here) so I'm mightily confused.

`renderDropDownList`

```
export const renderDropdownList = ({ input, data, valueField, textField }) =>
<DropdownList
    {...input}
    data={data}
    valueField={valueField}
    textField={textField}
    onChange={input.onChange}
/>;
```

Edit: As Prakash suggested, I tried to make a component and set the state, but that gives me `Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined` in console. Here's my component:

```
class Location extends Component {
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        data: []
    };

    this.getHouses = this.getHouses.bind(this);

}

componentDidMount() {
    this.getHouses()
}
getHouses = (e) =>  {
    let token = localStorage.getItem('id_token') || null;
    const AuthStr = 'Bearer '.concat(token);
    axios.get(BASE_URL + 'household/list', { headers: { Authorization: AuthStr } }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        let myData = response.data;

        console.log(myData);
        let list =[]
        for (let i = 0; i < myData._embedded.length; i++) {
            let embedded = myData._embedded[i];
            list.push(embedded.friendlyName);

        }
        console.log(list);
        this.setState({data:list});

    })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('error' + error);
        });
}

render()
{

    return(
        <div>
            <Field
                name="family"
                type="text"
                component={renderDropdownList}
                data={this.state.list}
                label="family"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="select your family"
            />
        </div>
        )
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show the renderDropdownList function?

Comment: yes, adding it to my question.

Comment: @SamiaRuponti Just set a component state when you get the list this way `this.setState({list:list})` and then pass that state to `Field` component this way `data={this.state.list}`.

Comment: @Prakashsharma setting state gives me the following error in console `Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined` . I'm updating with the component code.

Comment: Use arrow function for axios callback. So convert `function (response) {` to `(response) => {`. Also as you are setting `data` state so pass `this.state.data` to `Field` component not `this.state.list`.

Comment: thanks, it works now!